# Where does Visual Studio look for C++ header files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header

I checked out a copy of a C++ application from SourceForge (HoboCopy, if you're curious) and tried to compile it.

Visual Studio tells me that it can't find a particular header file. I found the file in the source tree, but where do I need to put it, so that it will be found when compiling?

Are there special directories?

Comment: Here I set an Windows Environment Variable pointing to the path where the library's .h is found. Then on QtCreator .pro qmake project file I refer to that environment variable. Is it possible to do a similar thing on Visual Studio? Refer to an environment variable which contains the path to the header file?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Visual Studio looks for headers in this order:

- In the current source directory.
- In the Additional Include Directories in the project properties (*Project* -> *[project name] Properties*, under C/C++ | General).
- In the Visual Studio C++ *Include directories* under *Tools* → *Options* → *Projects and Solutions* → *VC++ Directories*.
- In new versions of Visual Studio (2015+) the above option is deprecated and a list of default include directories is available at *Project Properties* → *Configuration* → *VC++ Directories*

In your case, add the directory that the header is to the project properties (*Project Properties* → *Configuration* → *C/C++* → *General* → *Additional Include Directories*).

Comment: Nice answer, but I must add, that in Visual Studio 2003, you should look at "Tools | Options | VC++ Directories" not "Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | VC++ Directories".

Comment: the preprocessor in VS 2010 looks into the current dir only if the quoted include syntax is used (e.g #include "whatever.h"). Using angle brackets (e.g #include <whatever.h>) omits the current dir ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=VS.100).aspx )

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010 and newer, the "standard C++ directories" is no longer under tools->options and is in a global property sheet: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx

Comment: I wonder that nobody yet told just the default directory. So, here it is `<root dir of Visual Studio>/VC/include/`. I have a MSVC in my job PC from the previous user, but I am use GNU/Linux, and don't wanted to launch VC just to satisfy my curiosity to look at Microsoft®'s headers. Btw, about what the kind of curiosity I had: I found that the MSDN didn't even knows it's own header names! I.e. they referred to `Iphlpapi.h`, but such a file not exist, it's name is rather `iphlpapi.h`, either `IPHlpApi.h`(both are there)! lol

Comment: Option "VS > Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories" is now depricated.

Comment: What is the "current source directory"?  Would the be the directory that the .vcxproj file is in?  Or another directory?

Comment: @cowlinator the current source directory is the directory that the source file is in. If you `#include "MyClass.h"` in `MyClass.cpp`, it will look in the same directory as the CPP file. You can also use relative paths.

Answer (score 48):

Actually, on my windows 10 with visual studio 2017 community, the path of the C++ header are:

1. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include`
2. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt`

The 1<sup>st</sup> contains standard C++ headers such as `<iostream>`, `<algorithm>`. The 2<sup>nd</sup> contains old C headers such as `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`. The version number can be different based on your software.

Comment: This is the most direct answer to OP. Though other answers talks about other issues, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @linrongbin I am scavenging the directories that were created by the latest VS Build Tools install. You're right about the first. But I unchecked the Windows SDK option, so that effectively means I don't have C headers, which in turn means the C++ workflow in BuildTools doesn't support C.

Answer (score 12):

If the project came with a Visual Studio project file, then that should already be configured to find the headers for you.  If not, you'll have to add the include file directory to the project settings by right-clicking the project and selecting Properties, clicking on "C/C++", and adding the directory containing the include files to the "Additional Include Directories" edit box.

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a bug in Visual Studio 2015 community. For a 64-bit project, the include folder isn't found unless it's in the win32 bit configuration *Additional Include Folders* list.

Comment: Do you have a link to this bug or a reference to it please?

Comment: No I found it myself and didn't report it

Comment: This bug still exist in Visual Studio Community 2019, I need to first add the include path to the win32 config, then add it again to the x64 config, apply the change, then it'll work. After that, going back to delete the path in the win32 one will still work.

Answer (score 7):

There exists a newer question what is hitting the problem better asking [How do include paths work in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2676417/5918623)

There is getting revealed the way to do it in the newer versions of VisualStudio

- **in the current project only** (as the question is set here too) as well as
- **for every new project as default**

The second is the what the answer of Steve Wilkinson above explains, what is, as he supposed himself, not the what Microsoft would recommend.

To say it the shortway here: do it, but do it in the User-Directory at

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0

in the XML-file

> Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props

and/or

> Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props

and not in the C:\program files - directory, where the unmodified Factory-File of Microsoft is expected to reside.

Then you do it the way as VisualStudio is doing it too and everything is regular.

For more info why to do it alike, see my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35591563/5918623).

Comment: If only the title had "C++" in it, and acknowledged the bug looking for 64 bit paths in the 32 bit path section

Comment: @Markus Other programming languages need include paths as well, I think it's actually nice that we don't have 500 different questions with the same answer, only difference being the name of the programming language in the title.

Comment: I disagree because each IDE and language would have its own way, so there could not be one answer for all languages.  The OP has updated the question to include C++.  If there is ever an exceptional language that doesn't have this answer applicable to it, how would you know?

Answer (score 6):

Tried to add this as a comment to [Rob Prouse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30827/rob-prouse)'s posting, but the lack of formatting made it unintelligible.

In Visual Studio 2010, the "Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | VC++ Directories" dialog reports that "VC++ Directories editing in Tools > Options has been deprecated", proposing that you use the rather counter-intuitive Property Manager.

If you really, really want to update the default $(IncludePath), you have to hack the appropriate entry in one of the XML files:

> \Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v100\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v100.props

or

> \Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v100\Microsoft.Cpp.X64.v100.props

(Probably not Microsoft-recommended.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks for files in the directory mentioned in options" cwd, you can include all sub directory under a path as shown below.

- it will create a single output file.
- it will compile all files together in the directory specified in **cwd**

project Structure:

moduelTest

```
-header_files
    - util.h
-source_files
    - util.c
    - main.c
```

[image]