# C++ Visual Studio Compilation error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I get the following compilation error

fatal error C1189: #error :  ERROR: Use of C runtime library internal header file.

I absolutely have no idea about it. can anyone throw some light on it?

The complete error:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\ce\include\crtdefs.h(100) : fatal error C1189: #error : ERROR: Use of C runtime library internal header file. Generating Code...

Comment: It would hope if you included the code or the name of the file that produces the error.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\ce\include\crtdefs.h(100) : fatal error C1189: #error :  ERROR: Use of C runtime library internal header file.
Generating Code...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've probably got `crt/src` in your include directory search path.  The headers in there are used to build the C Runtime - they aren't intended for use in user programs (even though they may have the same names as files that are intended to be included).

If you look in the header that's causing the problem, you'll probably see something like this:

```
/* This version of the header files is NOT for user programs.
 * It is intended for use when building the C runtimes ONLY.
 * The version intended for public use will not have this message.
 */
```

You need to fix your include search path.

I see you have `ce/include` in your include search path - are you building a WinCE application? If so, your build should be defining `_WIN32_WCE` to prevent this problem.  If not, this directory should not be in the include path.

Comment: This was close to my issue. I had to switch the target platform for a class library in my solution from PocketPC to Win32. Not sure how it started that way...

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit of precision, in my case I just needed to change the Include path of one of the .h files I used as shown below.

I started with this Include path :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src
```

and then changed it to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
```

which is where the right header file was located.

Comment: I know this is a old question, but I would like a little support. Where did you modified the include path? I looked at ../common/wince/qmake.conf and at the current qmake.conf, but I can't find it. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @Giox79 Unfortunately, I've completely forgotten what project of mine this was, but you can change a project's additional include directories in VC++. Project properties > (Debug/Release/etc.) > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories.

[link This page has further details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files#answer-335426) though VC++ now prefers not to use the third option.