# Using Windows header files within Netbeans 6.8

Tags: c++, netbeans6.8

I'm trying to make an windows application within Netbeans.
When using Visual studio it is no problem to use files like tchar.h

I have receaved a basic file structure containing those and I'm trying to get them to work on Netbeans IDE but it seems that Netbeans won't allow using files from Visual Studio.

I have tried to add the tchar.h file and all other file it required (including some C++ core files) and commenting the errors written in those care files:

> #error ERROR: Use of C runtime library internal header file.

But netbenas can't find the tchar.h file while being in same folder...

Comment: You may have dug up the wrong tchar.h when trying to fill in the dependencies?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494064/c-visual-studio-compilation-error

Comment: I took files from 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src

Those files didn't contain the mention that they weren't to be use for programming...

I tried to add VC/include to the include tab but just gives more errors (see next comment)

Comment: In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/../../../../include/w32api/windows.h:47,
/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include/stdarg.h:23:2: error: #error ERROR: Only Win32 target supported!

Comment: If you took them from crt/src (C runtime source) that sounds like a smoking gun on the "Use of C runtime library" error; but the rest is Windowsy and out of my bailiwick.

Comment: basically I'm trying to use the Visual studio windows libraries within netbeans...
Due to a genereal dislike of Visual Studio. 
But it seems allmost impossible...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gcc you might consider using the unix style wide characters instead of the microsoft specific version. Look at wchar.h

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wchar.h