# QT Wince Build: C++ Visual Studio Compilation error

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm trying to build the QT 4.8.5 version for a ARMv4i platform, with a custom SDK.
I performed the following steps (wince50standard-customarmv4i-msvc2008 is the folder under mkspecs that I created, copying the settings from wince50standard-armv4i-msvc2008 and changing the SDK name to the custom one):

- nmake confclean
- configure -platform win32-msvc2008 -xplatform wince50standard-customarmv4i-msvc2008
- Based on http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_Qt_on_Windows_CE , I used this additional command line (*-nomake examples -nomake demos -no-qt3support -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -opengl-es-cm -opensource -release -graphicssystem opengl -static*  (please note that results do not change if I remove this specific section of configuration)) and performed the following configure command:

**configure -platform win32-msvc2008 -xplatform wince50standard-avmarmv4i-msvc2008 -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-qt3support -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -opengl-es-cm -opensource -release -graphicssystem opengl –static**

- Now I get the following error message: *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\include\crtdefs.h(106) : fatal error C1189: #error :  ERROR: Use of C runtime library internal header file"*

I found this useful link, that seems strictly related to my problem (
  [C++ Visual Studio Compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494064/c-visual-studio-compilation-error)) but I don't understand how to fix the problem. 
How can I specify QT configure to avoid using the private set of crt header files and using those in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include"?

Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards

Comment: See this post of my:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660280/failure-on-building-qt5-from-source-on-windows/28679254#28679254

goodluck

Comment: First thank you for your help, I will give it a try. However I think your approach don't fix my problem, since I have it during the config phase, while your suggestion seems more related to the nmake step. Best regards Gio