# How to fix "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file" using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I installed "MS VS VC++ 2010 Express" for the first time after using Eclipse. I followed the instructions to install it at "[Setting Up GLFW in Visual Studio 2010](http://shawndeprey.blogspot.com/2012/02/setting-up-glfw-in-visual-studio-2010.html)".

Then I wrote this program to test it, which worked fine in Eclipse:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
using namespace std;



int wmain(){

    int running = GL_TRUE;


    if (!glfwInit()){
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    if (!glfwOpenWindow( 300,300 ,0,0,0,0,0,0, GLFW_WINDOW)){
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    while (running) {
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glfwSwapBuffers();

        running = !glfwGetKey (GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam (GLFW_OPENED);
    }




    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);



return 0;
}
```

And this is what it says in the console:

```
------ Build started: Project: first1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  first.cpp
c:\users\pc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\first1\first1\first.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glfw.h': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There might be a flaw in the installation process, if so, that what could be wrong?

Comment: You need to configure VS to know where you installed glfw's headers. You'll also need to configure the location of the glfw library(ies).

Comment: See the same question (and comments) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052938/cant-find-the-header-when-i-linka-lib-in-visual-studio-2012/17053027#17053027

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are missing setting up your include path.  You need to add the parent directory of the directory `GL` that contains all the include files for GLFW to either `Project Properties/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Include Directories` or `Project Properties/Configuration Properties/C/C++/General/Additional Include Directories`.