# Cannot open include file: 'occi.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, oracle

I am trying to compile an existing C++ project but get this error:

```
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'occi.h': No such file or directory
```

What I did is I went to this link:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html
```

and downloaded the first (basic) package.

Then unzipped the folder and modified PATH variable like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Atmel\sam-ba_2.12\drv\;C:\Program Files\Atmel\sam-ba_2.12;C:\Program Files\ATMEL Corporation\AT91-ISP v1.4\Library;C:\MSYS\1.0\bin;C:\MSYS\1.0\local\bin;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin;D:\instantclient_12_1
```

last being path to oracle.
But I still get the error, can someone help?

PS I noticed in my project there are lines like:

```
#include "occi.h"
```

Maybe it is because of this?

Comment: You need to specify where the compiler can find that include file using the `-I` option. Setting the `PATH` variable only affects where your system can find executable files or shared libraries.

Comment: why downvote? I asked clear question, and mentioned what I tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic package isn't enough. Its description says "All files required to **run** OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI application" (emphasis added); with just that you can *run* an OCI program, but you can't compile one. You need to download other instant client components. Specifically for the `occi.h` header you need the fifth file listed:

> *Instant Client Package - SDK: Additional header files and an example makefile for developing Oracle applications with Instant Client

If you download and unzip that in the same place you unzipped the basic package, your instant client directory will gain an `sdk` folder, which includes all the OCI header files.

You'll then need to compile with `-I D:\instantclient_12_1\sdk\include` so your compiler knows where to look for the `occi.h` and other header files. You may also need `-L` to tell it where to find the Oracle libraries; presumably you already have `-lclntsh` and/or `-locci`, which refer to libraries you should have already from the basic package.

Comment: @user200399 - I don't use that, but [this question might show you what you need to do](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2676417/266304).

Comment: `Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories` and add path to your instantclient/include folder.

Comment: As @Alex Poole already said, you also need to tell linker where to find Oracle libraries, you can do that with : `Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` and add path to your sdk/lib/msvc.

Comment: I am using VS 2017.  I have Oracle 19.13.0 installed.  I downloaded Intantclient_19_18 ( 
instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-19.18.0.0.0dbru.zip) and unzipped in my C: folder.  Then I followed @ElvisOric comments to set paths to the instant client include and Linker to sdk/lib/msvc paths.  Now, I am no longer getting "Cannot open include file occi.h, no such file or directory" but instead I am getting error ***LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\instantclient_19_3\sdk\lib\msvc\oraocci19d.lib'***.  Any help is highly appreciated