# LNK1181: cannot open input file 'oraocci10.lib'

Tags: c++, oracle

I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071362/cannot-open-include-file-occi-h-no-such-file-or-directory) problem before which I fixed (in Debug mode).
But now when I tried compiling my application in Release mode, I get this error:

> LNK1181: cannot open input file 'oraocci10.lib'

What can be causing this?

These are some my settings in the app:

### Debug Mode:

Linker->General->Additional Library Directories:

```
$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib;E:\app\vasyl\product\11.1.0\db_1\OCI\lib\MSVC\vc71;$(WXDIR284)\lib\vc_lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

### Release Mode:

Linker->General->Additional Library Directories:

```
$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib;\\darkstar\D$\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\oci\lib\msvc\vc71;$(WXDIR284)\lib\vc_lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

There is no drive named `E:` on my hdd btw.

**UPDATE**: Now that I check where I unarchived the oracle client I downloaded there is oraocci12.lib but I don't see the oraocci10.lib, see screen:
[image]
Maybe that is related to above error?

Comment: Why not change your release linker settings so that they are the same as your debug linker settings?

Comment: @john: Like this setting: "Linker->General->Additional Library Directories:"??

Comment: @john: Tried this but does not help. Actually please check the screen shot it seems I have those libs only for 12 version - but seems Debug version was not relying on version 10? I downloaded version 10 - now I see what I downloaded doesn't contain oraocci10.lib just oraoci10.dll. Where do I get the `oraocci10.lib` from?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downloading oraocci10.lib from here(it is contained inside a package):
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

Need to download correct package which is for version 10, SDK package (5th) -  `instantclient-sdk-win32-10.2.0.5.zip`.
Unzip it and specify the path to the lib in Linker->General->Additional Library directories