# C++ need to include headers many directories up

Tags: c++, header-files, organization, code-organization

I have the following folder structure in a 2D terraria/Minecraft style game:

```
src/
- Backend/
- - Vector.hpp
- World/
- - Elements/
- - - Mobs/
- - - - BaseMob.cpp
```

As you would guess, there are plenty more source files within each directory. Inside `BaseMob.cpp` I need to access `src/Backend/Vector.hpp`. **Is there either a cleaner way to write `#include "../../../Backend/Vector.hpp"` (ie. `#include "/Backend/Vector.hpp"`) or a better way to organize the files in my source folder?**

Here's some more info on the actual content in the source folders (most `.cpp` files are excluded):

```
Backend/ # Anything specific to a particular platform
- Vector.hpp
- Graphics.hpp
World/ # Anything about the whole game's world
- Elements/
- - Mobs/
- - - BaseMob.hpp # Polymorphic base class
- - - MobHandler.hpp # Manages all mobs in world
- - - PlayerMob.hpp
- - - WaterMob.hpp
- - Block.hpp # Defines all possible blocks
- - Inventory.hpp
- - Furnace.hpp
- World.hpp
- WorldRenderer.hpp # Makes calls to Backend/graphics.hpp
main.cpp
```

Comment: You could use a makefile or alter your system path.

Comment: Organize the files in the most logical way, then stick to a consistent rule for referencing them. For example Google IIRC recommends absolute paths rather than relative. Makes sense if you move files around a lot, I prefer a balance, may be one level up/down relative the rest absolute...

Comment: I would probably do `#include "Backend/Vector.hpp"` however it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider reorganizing your include folders. This is a possible solution but may not be enough: You won't be able to do that when you'll start using 3rd party libraries...so you need a better way to fix that.

Clean way is to add needed folders (the one where the header files you need are stored) to your "includes path" used by the compiler, so that it can find them.

Then, instead of `#include "World/Elements/Mobs/BaseMob.hpp"`, you add `World/Elements/Mobs` to the include paths and then simply do `#include "BaseMob.hpp"`

- For instance, if you use gcc: [How to add a default include path for gcc in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)
- For Visual studio: [How do include paths work in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676417/how-do-include-paths-work-in-visual-studio)
  ...

If you use a different compiler/IDE, it must provide an option to do that.

Comment: Recommend throwing in an example like `#include "World/Elements/Mobs/BaseMob.hpp"` just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend refraining from placing paths in #include statements.  If the file moves, you'll have to change all the sources.

IMO, a better method is to tell the compiler where to look for the include files.  A common command line compiler option is "-I" (capital letter i).  In IDEs there may be a setting where you can list all the paths to search.

By telling the compiler where to search, you include files can be anywhere and can move and you don't have to change the source code.

Comment: But doesn't this also open a can of worms? By using -I, wouldn't "World/Renderer.hpp" and Menu/Renderer.hpp create a problem?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work for files with same names in different directories.  However I usually have unique filenames, such as `MenuRenderer.hpp` and `WorldRenderer.hpp`, so I don't have the issue.