# Visual Studio 2015 c++ cannot open include file error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, include, include-path

I have been trying to figure out this error for a while now but I cannot find anything, whenever I try to build my program I get the error:

C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h' No such file or directory.

**edit: I added $(UniversalCRT_IncludePath) into additional include directories but I still get the error.**

[Attempting to add into additional include directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4mF7.png)

[Code and Error Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az10B.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do include paths work in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676417/how-do-include-paths-work-in-visual-studio)

Comment: **Don't** post code and error messages as images. Post as **text** *directly* in the question.

Comment: I posted the error in text the code is irrelevant as there is nothing wrong with the code itself @JesperJuhl

Answer (score 1):

You should check `Additional Include Directories` parameter for your C++ project.

To do that, go `Project -> Properties -> C/C++` and add `$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)` to `Additional Include Directories` parameter.

More information about Universal CRT can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/).

Comment: I did that you can find the photo in my question, is it correct? @Nikita

Comment: @Tylv Yes, it's correct. If it's not working, check `VC++ Directories`. It should contains `$(VC_IncludePath)`. This macros should point to your Windows 10 Kit ucrt include folder.

Comment: @Tylv I mean `VC++ Directories -> Include Directories`

Comment: in my include directories for vc++ it says $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);

I believe this to be the correct

Comment: @Tylv Check how `$(VC_IncludePath)` macros is interpreted. To do that click Macros button at `Include Directories` parameters page. You should see value as a full directory path, e.g. `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt`

Comment: just running an update to see if that helps, do you have an email I can contact you on if I am still having issues or is it easiest to contact you on here?

Comment: @Tylv It's better to contact here

Comment: @Tylv By the way, check that you have [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) installed

Comment: Perfect, will update you as soon as possible, it's a big update though @Nikita

Comment: I definitely do have Windows 10 SDK installed