# Visual Studio Additional Includes Directories $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I am migrating C++ projects from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2015. 
Previously there were additional include directories pointing to 
Microsoft Platform SDK VS2010\Include which is an older version of the SDK. I am now using $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) which solves the issues I was having by pointing to the older SDK version.

My question is how does this path resolve the SDK version to use?

If there are multiple versions of Visual Studio installed on the machine which SDK version will be used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676417/how-do-include-paths-work-in-visual-studio

Comment: Project > Properties > General > Target Platform Version setting.  You still target older versions by setting the `_WIN32_WINNT` macro correctly.  And, heaven forbid, XP and SDK7 by changing the Platform Toolset to v140_xp.