# How do I get Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 to link to the OpenCV 3.4 libraries?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, opencv3.0

I have downloaded:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (14.0)

Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x64 (14.12.25810)

And OpenCV 3.4

I try to get this stackoverflow program to run.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

usingnamespacecv;
usingnamespacestd;

intmain()
{
    Matim = imread("c:/full/path/to/lena.jpg");
    if(im.empty())
    {      
        cout<<"Cannotloadimage!"<< endl;
        return -1;
    }   
    imshow("Image", im);  
    waitKey(0);}
```

But I get an error:

```
cannot open source file 

"opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

I have searched:

Opencv.org

Docs.opencv.org

Learnopencv.com

Stackoverflow.com

Gethub.com

Quora.com

AI shack

Google

None of these sites have given me an accurate solution to my first step modern problem.  I have not found a way to #enclude the libraries.  Does someone know the information that I am looking for?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975661/6610379

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer is at:

Installing OpenCV 2.4.3 in Visual C++ 2010 Express [closed]

Realize that it must be updated for Visual Studio 2017 and OpenCV 3.4

Answer (score 1):

Try to include Opencv3.4\build\include in configuration properties in C/C++ and set lib file and .lib name in Linker paths.