# Visual Studio C++ "Function definition not found" on include

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, include, detours

I downloaded the [`detours`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52586) source code and compiled it with [`nmake`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/nmake-reference). Now I want to include it in a `C++` project [so I added the include directory path to the include directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975661/3764804) as well as the `#include "detours.h"` on top of the `C++` source file. The previously unresolved `detours.h` is now fixed however I still get `Function definition not found` errors in the `detours.h` file itself:

[image]

This causes a few linker errors like the following:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _DetourTransactionBegin@0 referenced in function "unsigned long __stdcall InitializeHooks(void *)" (?InitializeHooks@@YGKPAX@Z)
```

The `detours` folder looks like this:
[image]

I already cleaned the solution and rebuilt it but the errors persist. Is there anything else I need to do to make it work? How do I tell `Visual Studio` where to look up the function definitions since specifying the `includes` doesn't seem to be enough?

Comment: Did you link with the library, where such function is defined in? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: No but thanks, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to pass the `.lib` files to the linker as well:

[image]

Furthermore adding the libraries to the `Library Directories` path so the `.lib` files can be found at all.

Now the linker errors are gone.