# C++ include error from #include "DevEngine/Core.h"

Tags: c++, include

So there are 1 files that I want to link together, Core.h and Events.h.

Core.h is in a folder called DevEngine and the Events.h file is in a folder called Events witch is inside DevEngine.

Here are the file directorys:

- Core.h = src/DevEngine/Core.h
- Events.h = src/DevEngine/Events/Events.h

I have added a `#include "DevEngine/Core.h"` : Cannot open include file: 'DevEngine/Core.h': No such file or directory DevEngine. I don't know where I have went wrong.

I have tried: #include "../DevEngine/Core.h". That still gives me a error.

Comment: ***I have added a #include "DevEngine/Core.h" : Cannot open include file: 'DevEngine/Core.h': No such file or directory DevEngine. I don't know where I have went wrong.*** Is the folder containing the `DevEngine` folder in the include search path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `#include "../Core.h"`.

You can also set the directories the compiler uses to search for the header files ([-I option in gcc](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html)) and then use paths to those files relative to one of those directories. (See for example [gcc documentation on search paths](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).)

This could be done differently depending on the way you are building the project.

For Visual Studio, look in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676417/how-do-include-paths-work-in-visual-studio).

For CMake, use [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html#include-directories).