# Additional steps required for including header files using VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I've recently moved my project to a new home, but(of course) the build is failing.

In the picture below 1 represents the old directory that these files were located in and 2 represents the new include directory I've added.
[image: Added directory]

I've also copied and pasted the files into their new home...
[image: Files in place]

Are there additional steps that need to be taken other than just manually moving the files into the given files into a directory, and then specifying that directory as an include directory?
I've read through and implemented most, if not all, of the answers from the following 2 posts and I am still having the issue.

[Where does Visual Studio look for C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files#:%7E:text=If%20not%2C%20you%27ll%20have,Additional%20Include%20Directories%22%20edit%20box.)

[How do include paths work in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676417/how-do-include-paths-work-in-visual-studio)

I've also toyed around with using quotes vs. angle brackets to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building `Debug` configuration, but show properties for `Release`. Make sure the additional include is the same.

Also, you masked the path to the `Documents` folder; is the path the same?

Comment: Omg, I knew it was something obvious that I had missed.

Thank you.