# header file <coff.h> not exist even installed with correct configurations

Tags: c

**This is not a duplicate, because it related to the Visual Studio SDK, not a single header file.**

I was building a COFF parser using Visual Studio SDK, but IDE says the header doesn't exist, e.g. "coff.h".

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <coff.h>


int main(int, char* argv[])
{
}
```

Why it doesn't exist?
File search result:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include>dir coff.h /s
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is EED9-4506
File Not Found

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include>cd ..\..

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC>dir coff.h /s
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is EED9-4506
File Not Found
```

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: What path does a search for the file coff.h turn up?

Comment: @Randommm `cannot open source file "coff.h"`

Comment: You need to install `linux-headers`.

Comment: @AllanWind "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" and all files in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\"

Comment: @DaBler Didn't you read the question? It says "Visual Studio SDK".

Comment: The `/usr/include/linux/coff.h` is part of linux headers. If you think that `coff.h` is part of Visual Studio SDK, locate this file on your disk.

Comment: @DaBler already post the directory which is searched, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include"

Comment: Then add this path to your header files search path (somewhere in the setup of project, I don't know exactly where because I use Linux.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256146/discussion-between-winapiadmin-and-dabler).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the results of your file search, and _that you found the header file in there_. Please add how you setup your project to include that path.

Comment: `coff.h` is not supposed to be part of any Windows SDK. So I'm not really getting what you're asking here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky When did I asking for Windows SDK?

Comment: @winapiadmin Sorry, then I misunderstood the question. You're mentioning "correct configurations" in the question title. Tell us more about that. What "correct configurations" are you talking about? Did _you_ put the coff.h file somewhere? You're asking "Why it doesn't exist?". Why do you think it should exist somewhere?

Comment: Did you install the Visual Studio SDK? I would expect that it has a include file hierarchy separate from the standard include file tree. Did you try a brute-force search on your complete disk to locate "coff.h"? How did you setup your project?

Comment: If you found the file in the directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include why does your subsequent `dir` not show it?  and "all files in" doesn't make sense to me.  How can *all* files match your search for coff.h?  As noted above once you located the file and you have access to it as the current user add that path to your project.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676417/how-do-include-paths-work-in-visual-studio for how to do that.