# Visual Studio C++ include path order for nested include files

Tags: c++, include

I found the article [Where does Visual Studio look for C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files) to be a good start, but I have further questions.  The general order that VS looks for include files are (1) local directory, (2) those specified with /I, and (3) those specified by the environment (INCLUDE env var or VC++ settings).

Q1. I think that the /X option turns off (3).  Right?  Or does it also turn off (1)?

Q2. If I have a nested include file (main.c includes inc1.h, which includes inc2.h), where the first included file is found in one of the /I folders, does VS look for the second included file starting in that same /I folder, or just the local folder of the original source file?  VS2008 seems to be operating the first way, but I'd like to find it documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `/X` option will not disable looking for files in the local directory (assuming you are including them like `"this.h"` rather than `<this.h>`). You can easily test this by creating a file

```
  #include "foo.h"
  int main() {}
```

creating an empty `foo.h`, and compiling using the `/X` flag.

For Q2, my test with VC2010 showed it behaves the same as VC2008. What I did was had a main:

```
  #include "inc1.h"
  int main() {}
```

with a folder inc that contained an inc1.h that just

```
  #include "inc2.h"
```

with two different `inc2.h` files; on in `inc` and one in the directory with my source file. The one in my source directory was empty, the one in `inc` had an `#error` directive. In general, you don't want to rely on this though. Both the C and C++ standards simply say on `#include` that "the named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner".

Comment: I found on MSDN some more details about the #include directive.  Basically, the 'local directory' means the folder of the file with the #include statement, followed by any file that included it, etc, up to the original source file.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Q1. The `/X` option does turn off the `INCLUDE` var, but not the local directory (see Q2)

Q2. C and C++ compilers, for nested include files, make the location of an include file the current local directory, so you can't turn it off.

eg.
If your `inc.h` file is found in one of the `/I` folders and it tries to include a file like this:
`#include "foo/foo.h"` then it must use its own local directory first, before all the other `/I` folders as they all might have a `foo` folder with a `foo.h` file and your `inc.h` file would probably not compile as its just included the wrong header file.

I've just found this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28VS.90%29.aspx) for VS2008 which seems to have a complete explanation.