# #include absolute path syntax in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, path, include, absolute

For some reason, I need to use the absolute path in `#include` for my system.

Is using `#include "D:\temp\temp_lib\temp.h"` acceptable?

I have tried these different usage and it all seems to work.

1. `#include "D:\temp\temp_lib\temp.h"`
2. `#include "D:\\temp\\temp_lib\\temp.h"`
3. `#include "D:/temp/temp_lib/temp.h"`

I just want to know which one should I use? I am using MSVC 2005. I'm wondering if all three will still work in Linux or other environment.

I was expecting #1 to be an error during compilation, but I did not get any. Anyone has any idea why that is?

Comment: I say you use whichever you feel most comfortable with. And no, _none_ will work in a Linux (or OSX) environment, as no other system than Windows (and DOS) have drive letters. The closest is the one with forward slashes (`/`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg good point. :) `D:/`

Comment: It is better to determine - why do you need absolute paths. I think if you'll explain us that - we will suggest a solution which will help you to avoid that. And yes - all of them will not work in Linux.

Comment: @denys A perfectly good reason is having a debug header with some debug tool function outside source control, which I only include for debug sessions and do not actually commit. Yet I reuse them and want to be able to put them in&out as fast as possible. Absolute path allows that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every implementation I'm aware of, and certainly MSVC 2005 and linux, allows you to specify the directory paths in which to find header files. You should include D:\temp\temp_lib on the list of directory paths, and then use

```
#include <temp.h>
```

For gcc, use -I *path*. For MSVC, see [Where does Visual Studio look for C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files)

The reason that #1 isn't a syntax error is that, although it looks like a string literal, it isn't. The specification is

```
#include "q-char-sequence"
```

Where q-char is

> any member of the source character set except the new-line character
>   and "

In particular, `\` has no special meaning. The interpretation of the q-char-sequence is implementation-defined.

Comment: This is good explanation. But I tried this line:
#include "D:\temp\new\new_file.h"

and still MSVC was able to find new_file.h. I am expecting an error on this since this contains a new-line character (\n).

Anyone has any idea why MSVC was able to find the file?

I did not set -I path to D:\temp\new in the MSVC also. So, I am confused why MSVC was still able to find the file.

Comment: @chrisyo \n is not a newline character ... a newline character is (in ASCII) ctrl-j. \n is an escape sequence that the C compiler *interprets* as a newline character .... but not here; again, "\ has no special meaning". 'why MSVC was still able to find the file' -- because you gave it an absolute path, so it didn't need to look it up on the path list. The reason I recommended using the path list is because you said you want it work in Linux, but your Windows path won't work there.