# C- Readline() undefined reference

Tags: c

i am trying to run this code but the compiler fails : undefined reference to ' readline ' and undefined reference to ' add_history ' .I am using CodeBlocks .This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main()
{
    char *buf;



    while((buf = readline("\n >> "))!=NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(buf,"quit")==0)
            break;

        printf("[%s]\n",buf);

        if (buf[0]!=0)
            add_history(buf);
    }

    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the `readline` folder to your search path, and then `#include <readline.h>`  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12563042

Comment: What readline folder ?

Comment: The one that you claim `readline.h` is residing in.

Comment: If you want to reference a project file, you enclose its name with `"..."` not with `<...>` the latter references the compiler library.

Comment: Ah, true.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593

Comment: Add `-lreadline` to your compiler command.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `undefined reference` has nothing to do with includes.

Comment: `readline()` is not a C standard library function. So you have to include the library it's in and any header files needed, as well as tell the linker where to find it.

Comment: This is what i done , but still same thing : #include "/home/myname/Downloads/readline-6.3/readline.h"
#include <readline/readline.h>

Comment: what is the platform you work with? e.g. in ubuntu you might need to have `libreadline6-dev` and `libreadline6` installed, and to compile your code with `-lreadline`

Comment: @iharob: I think we've already covered that.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu . I tried to install it , when i do 'make install' , it tries to put the readline in the include folder and it gives an error : persmission denied, so it fails

Comment: You do not, I repeat, not install software from sources. Do not invoke `./configure && make && make install`, do not pass go. Install packages from the repository using your package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just ensure the development files for readline are installed for which you need to run this as the root user

```
# apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

as someone mentioned in the comments.

Next, you go to the `Project->Build Options` menu and a dialog pops up
[image: Build Options Dialog]

then go to the `Linker Settings` tab[image: Linker Settings Tab]

now just click the `Add` button, and type `readline` in the dialog that pops up [image]

click `Ok`, and try building now, it should work.