# Stringify a C macro that contains a word with number

Tags: c

```
/* Example.h */

#define QUOTE(str)                      #str
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(str)           QUOTE(str)

#define HOUSTON_INCLUDE_PATH            u:/PlatformPkgs/HoustonPkg/Include
#define HOUSTON1_INCLUDE_PATH           u:/PlatformPkgs/Houston1Pkg/Include

// HOUSTON1 is defined in CFLAGS with /DHOUSTON1
#if defined(HOUSTON)   
#include EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(HOUSTON_INCLUDE_PATH/Optional.h)
#elif defined (HOUSTON1)
#include EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(HOUSTON1_INCLUDE_PATH/Optional.h)
#endif
```

Got the compiling error below:

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'u:/PlatformPkgs/1/Include/Optional.h': No such file or directory
```

The error is due to the macro is expanded to`u:/PlatformPkgs/1/Include/Optional.h`. It stripped out `Houston` and `Pkg` in `Houston1Pkg`. How can I retain the whole word `Houston1Pkg` in the path?

Comment: It doesn't happen with `gcc` I suppose you are using `MSVC`?

Comment: Yep, just tested with gcc, cannot reproduce

Comment: Is `Houston1Pkg` defined as `#define Houston1Pkg 1` somewhere?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562807/include-absolute-path-syntax-in-c-c

Comment: I use MSVC.  Houston1Pkg is the folder name.

Comment: You normally specify the location of the headers via a compiler command line option; on Unix, `-Iu:/PlatformPkgs/Houston1Pkg/Include`, and `/I:\PlatformPkgs\Houston1Pkg\Include` with MSVC, I believe.

Comment: I edit the original post. I understand to specify the location of the header via compiler flag. This issue is different, the optional.h file is reside in two different folders (Houston and Houston1) and the content of optional.h is different between these two folders.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree that this question is not particularly related to the suggested duplicate, which has to do with backslashes in the filepath. This question shows an apparently vanishing path segment, which is not related. (I also think RSahu asked the right question; it needs a reply.) Voting to reopen.

Comment: @rici: I don't agree with the reopen, but I'll let the processes take their due course. If that's not the answer, then the probable answer to the plain question is almost certainly `#undef Houston1Pkg` before the block of lines with the `#include` in the shown code. In other words, I expect `Houston1Pkg` is defined as `1` somewhere in the system, either on the command line or in a header (or, perhaps, in the other code before this in the source code).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I do, too, which is why I think RSahu asked the right question. Indeed, the answer you suggest is likely correct, but it cannot be provided as an answer because the question is closed. Not that it matters much -- it's pretty localized. Although I think I remember a question which asks, roughly, "how can I write a macro which will stringify its argument without macro expanding the argument first?"

Comment: @HungHo: There's no problem.  When you need to pick the Houston1Pkg header, you specify that as the path and simple write `#include <Optional.h>` in the code.  When you need to pick the HoustonPkg header, you specify that as the path on the command line.  So, the path chosen is specified on the command line.  All else apart, many machines don't have a `U:` drive.  I can simulate it on Unix as a relative pathname, of course.

Comment: #undef Houston1Pkg fixed the problem.  Thanks everyone for the help