# C++ Referencing files in other Projects

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am wondering how would I reference a file from another project in C++.

For example, I have moved `avocado.h` from my Vegetable project to Fruit project. In fruit.cpp, I am trying to include `avocado.h`, but the compiler cannot find `avocado.h`.

```
Original recipie.cpp:
    #include "avocado.h" //error c1083: Cannot open included file: 'avocado.h':No such file or directory
```

My existing solution is to use namespaces, but I am wondering if it will be much more efficient for me to somehow tell `#include` exactly where to look?

```
Current recipie.cpp:
namespace fruit {
    class avocado;
}
```

EDIT - Sorry, I should mention that I am working in a Solution (or library) where both Fruit and Vegetable projects are under the same solution.

Comment: If you want to create two or more projects that share a file, consider creating a library that the projects can use.

Comment: There are ways to set the include directories (depending on your compiler) which are the directories the compiler looks for the header files. Additionally you can use relative paths such as `#include "../Vegetable/avocado.h"`.

Comment: @nwp Is there a way to use an absolute path?

Comment: The compiler will have flags to tell it where to look for headers. Like `GCC` does this `g++ -I/path/to/header/dir ...`

Comment: Apparently [you can use absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562807), but it is a really bad idea because it locks the project into essentially only working on your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've moved the header from one project to another, you should probably move it physically, as well, in same directory as `recipie.cpp`. Alternatively, you can change the `Fruit` project properties: `Configuration Properties \ VC++ Directories \ Include Directories` to include the path to `avocado.h`