# unable to compile examples in ODEINT package

Tags: c++, boost, ode

I am trying to solve a coupled set of ODE's in C++, and I have decided that I want to try out odeint ([available here](http://headmyshoulder.github.com/odeint-v2/)) as I have read many good things about it. However I am having compiling the examples that are included in the package. Here is the situation:

So far I have only downloaded the package and extracted it. I am running Visual C++ 6 on Windows XP and I am compiling the example "simple1d". I get the error message: "Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory".

It is not clear to me what I am missing. Do I need the full boost library to make this work? I was under the impression that ODEINT is a "standalone" package.

Comment: Sorry, odeint is not standalone. It depends on boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error says that compiler can not find the boost libraries. You should download them from boost.org and also add them to your header path.

Comment: Now I am linking to both ODEINT and BOOST and then I get 10 errors and 3192 warnings (?!). One of the errors are (as an example): "c:\boost_1_51_0\boost\utility\swap.hpp(37) : error C2265: '<Unknown>' : reference to a zero-sized array is illegal"

Comment: Can you try another example? Simple1d is some kind of special. Although I did not experienced any problems until now.

Comment: Yes, I just tried "solar_system.cpp". Now I get 4 errors (no warnings), and one of them is: "error C2039: 'abort' : is not a member of 'std'"

Comment: Hmm, maybe Visual Studio 6 is too old, maybe not. We never heard from people having problems with MSVC. Maybe your try a newer version of MSVC? They come with a Express variant which is free.

Comment: I'll try -- I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Well, visual c++ 6 was released in 1998! Maybe, indeed, newer versions of boost aren't supported for such ancient IDEs. Does trivial code compile? Like including the boost headers but with a trivial main function? Does the "'abort' : is not a member of 'std'" message go away if you `#include <cstdlib>`?

Comment: OK, I updated to MSVC++ 2010 and now the examples work. When I build and compile it usually takes 2-3 seconds, is that normal? It seems like a long time, but then again - there are many files in the library.

Comment: Two or three seconds is ok. odeint heavily uses the C++ template system which usually results in higher compilation timer but better run times.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you download and extract the package to? The package homepage says that it's a header-only package, so you only need to let Visual find the header files. I haven't used Visual in a while, but a quick google of something like "Visual 6 add header path" should be a good place to start. Take a look at [Where does Visual Studio look for C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files).

Quoting from [this page](http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vc6.html):

> Within Visual Studio, go to the **Project Settings** dialog. We want to change the settings for both Debug and Release versions, so under the **Settings For** field, select "All Configurations". Under the **C/C++** Tab, select **Preprocessor** options.

The package tarball has a directory called *boost*: you want to add the path of that directory into the **Additional include directories** box and then `#include <boost/numeric/odeint/config.hpp>` in your code.

**Update**

It appears, then, that you already have the odeint headers installed properly: the file boost/numeric/odeint/config.hpp has a line `#include <boost/config.hpp>`, which is what visual must be complaining about; so I guess the package is not standalone. It must need other boost header files installed. I can't find anything in either the package homepage or the package tarball that mentions any dependencies, so I suppose you should try to install boost too. Download [version 1.51.0 here](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_51_0.html), and [this is the windows documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/windows.html).

Comment: I tried out your suggestion, but it didn't help. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You must download  odeint from http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/downloads.html and Boost c++ libraries from http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_51_0.html.
If you use codeblocks right click your project, select build oprions, select Search Directories and add two references one for odeint and one for boost.