# C++ cannot open source file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In C++ with Visual studio 2017,

I copied some header files into my project folder, then added them under the "solution explorer" in c++. Now when I write

```
#include "name.h"
```

it prints an error under include, and says "cannot open source file".

Why, and what can I potentially do to fix it?

I only just downloaded VS and am learning c++ for the first time.

Comment: Verify your "Additional Include Directories" in your project properties

Answer (score 23):

If you're using Visual studio, right click on the project and then on Properties, Under Configuration Properties click on C\C++ and then add the directory to your header files under the Additional Include Directories section.

Answer (score 3):

There is more information here on how to deal with this problem: [Where does Visual Studio look for C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files)

For me, I followed xflowXen's answer and then at "Include Directories" typed in the specific pathname where my header file was located followed by a semicolon, something like:
C:\Users\name\source\repos\p2-A\p2-A;
then applied the changes and the issue went away.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still scratching their heads, you're not "supposed to" #include your own headerfiles with triangle quotes (<>), You're supposed to use "Quotation marks". It is a common mistake.

Comment: Quotes will loc LOCALLY first, and then in the INCLUDE paths (specified in a variety of forms). Braces will NOT look locally but will look in the SAME INCLUDE paths. 

As a result "your own" header files has a very specific meaning (files that are specified relative to the .cpp/.c) and not "hey I wrote those"

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio (or rather the compiler) needs to know where to look for the included file. Check out your include path in your VS project.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: This question was just recently updated, this answer is no longer relevant.*

For anyone here that still hasn't found a way to fix this, try to modify/redownload Python with the boxes for **Download debugging symbols** and **Download debug binaries** Checked.

Read more at a [mslearn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-symbols-for-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python?view=vs-2022#download-symbols) and this helpful [tutorial site](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python.h-no-such-file-or-directory/#:%7E:text=Once%20the%20include%20and%20linker%20paths%20are%20added%2C,give%20the%20file%20a%20name%20and%20click%20add.) called DelftStack.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer is good if you use Microsoft Visual Studio IDE.

This error usually occurs when the compiler cannot find the header file.

You can try the following steps:

1. Right-click on the project name in the Solution Explorer window.
2. Select *Properties*.
3. Under *Configuration Properties*, click on *C/C++*.
4. Under *General*, add the directory to your header files under the *Additional Include Directories* section.
5. Save your changes and try building your project again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties and set configuration and platform to ALL and then under C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories add $(SolutionDir)(use this if your solution is stored where your project is stored if not then navigate wherever you have stored your projects header files and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, Right click on project and in *Configuration Properties* find *C/C++* and then *General*/
In The window at the right side pick up a directory at *Additional Include Directories* row.

All these steps described above to resolve problem of finding header file work if you perform them both for 64-bit and for 32-bit platform. Or you can choose all Platforms item in the Configuration settings above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35373787)

Answer (score 0):

if none of above answers does not solve your problem I would suggest changing your included header to one that match your case as example instead of using (for windows):

```
#include <unistd.h> //read() , write() , sleep()..
```

you can use:

```
#include <io.h>  // _read() , _write() 
#include <windows.h>  //sleep()
```

**make sure that your system support included headers**

I wish it solved future problems.