# c++ default include path

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos

Is there a way (in C++) to find the system C++ header path according to the OS (Linux, Windows, macOS) and compiler.

For instance, if I'm on Windows I would like find the default C++ header directory used by Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Visual Studio look for C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files)

Comment: and for Linux, use  `g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to found the c++ header folder with c++ code lines and not with command line.
i.e. found the visual studio version and root intall falder ( idm for mingw, clang, gcc, xcode ...) and deduct the c++ header folder.

Comment: You could run that command *from* the code.