# How to open project properties in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to open Project Properties window in VS 2017 in order to add header files in a way described in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files) However it turned out to be very frustrating as when I reproduce steps described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2017) (Project -> [project name] Properties), I end up with a different window, missing some content that is crucial in my case (Common Properties -> C/C++).

What I expect:
[image: What I expect]

What I get:
[image]

How do I open the window that contains Common Properties?

Comment: The properties for a C# project are very, very different from a C++ project.  Nobody can really tell how you got so confused or what you actually want to accomplish, makes it quite hard to help you.

Comment: Indeed, it turned out I can't add headers to a c# project. My confusion came from an external sdk I was trying to implement, that has a common documentation for C# and C++, which did not mension that. Having not much knowledge in the topic I blindly followed the instructions which were only meant for the C++ case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that window can only be opened in C/C++ project, not in C#