# Install geos on Visual Studio using VCPKG

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, vcpkg, geos

I use Visual Studio 2017 Community. I have installed geos 3.9.1#1 via VCPKG and confirmed all is OK with 'vcpkg.exe list':

[image]

However, in VS I can't #include <geos.h> in my project: the compiler reports it 'cannot open source file geos.h'.

Which steps do I still need to carry out to finish the installation? These are not obvious in the documentation.

FYI: the answer to the question  [Where does Visual Studio look for C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files) does not answer this question.

Update:
I tried to debug the problem by looking for the geos.h file in the vcpkg include folder but it was not found.  I found only one instance of geos.h here:

> source\repos\vcpkg\vcpkg\buildtrees\geos\src\3.9.1-1acf7d5768.clean\include.

There was no sign of this file in the folder that I would expect it to be in:

> source\repos\vcpkg\vcpkg\packages\geos_x64-windows\include

Comment: This should help: [https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/) make sure you did step 2 and executed `.\vcpkg integrate install` and restarted Visual Studio after doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have carried this out but still get the same compiler message with #include. BTW: I recently installed xtensor using the same method and had no problems.

Comment: You probably need to investigate the reason for this yourself. What I mean look at the include folder in the vcpkg tree and try to figure out where `geos.h` is in that folder.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, the folder does not contain geos.h, just geos_c.h. However, I can't #include to that file either. It's in 'source\repos\vcpkg\vcpkg\packages\geos_x64-windows\include'.

Comment: I uninstalled geos then reinstalled it. I found only one instance of geos.h here: source\repos\vcpkg\vcpkg\buildtrees\geos\src\3.9.1-1acf7d5768.clean\include. There was no sign of this file in the folder that I would expect it to be in: source\repos\vcpkg\vcpkg\packages\geos_x64-windows\include

Comment: It may be a bug in that package. You may want to submit an issue on the microsoft github page.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Problem solved. I had installed the x64 verssion but selected the x86 solution on my IDE. When I changed the IDE to to x84 I could #include to geos.h